# How do I ensure the formatting for the `select` input works on Mac OS

Tags: html, css, macos, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

How do I keep the formatting consistent for my form across all OS's.

Atm, it is working perfectly fine on Windows, however - I want the `select` input to have the same formatting on Mac OS and iOS as well as Android phones.

The image below is the `select` field within a Safari browser. The same formatting is on a Chrome browser on Mac OS too.

I have attached an image for reference [Select Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is417.png)

From the above image you can see the `Contact Number` and `Name` field formatting is the same, however the format changes for `Debt Level` unfortunately.

Comment: Drop down menus are browser specific. If you need different behavior than the one browser offers, you need to write your own drop down menu.

Comment: did you try any CSS yourself at ALL?

Answer (score 1):

Every browser has their own styling for native elements like selects. You could try to set your own specific styles on them to override some styles but browsers will ignore most CSS rules on selects.

If you want to have complete power over styling the select, you'll need to implement your own custom version. This outlines what would need to be done: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/#article-header-id-4

Answer (score 0):

I cant add a comment, so have to put it as an answer

if you are using bootstrap, define ui:bootstrap cdn in the script tag.